# Generate image with PHP

Tags: php, image

I want to ask how to generate image with php.

One background image, one image on center of this background and text.

Everything positioning by X,Y.! With PHP image library

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8k5b.jpg)

Thanks for help  I want to know some really basic example how to make background with image and text, nothing else.

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) - The [manual](http://php.net/imagecreate) is a good place to start.

Comment: try this http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php for a start. You will find many examples on SO as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982732/php-gd-align-text-center-horizontally-and-decrease-font-size-to-keep-it-inside/15983127#15983127 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some great libraries in PHP to genereate Image you can use GD (Documentation here : http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) ou , Imagemagick (Documentation here http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), But as far as I remember Imagemagick is not installed with PHP you have to add it

Here is an example (Didn't tried it)

```
$background = imagecreatefrompng('back.png');
$im = imagecreatefrompng('image.png');
$marginLeft = (imagesx($background)-imagesx($im))/2; 
$marginTop = (imagesy($background)-imagesy($im))/2; 
imagecopy($background , $im , $marginLeft , $marginTop , 0 , 0 , imagesx($im) , imagesy($im));
$font_file = './arial.ttf'; 
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00); 
imagefttext($background, 13, 0, $marginLeft , $marginTop + imagesy($im), $black, $font_file, 'My Text');
```

Comment: Thanks for help i know about this libraries, but I want to know some realy basic example how to make background with image and text, nothing else.

Comment: @DARK_DUCK
Thanks! And please how to save it as a file?

Comment: add imagepng($background, 'sample.png');